# How to approach if a,b,c ⊨ d then a→d OR b→d OR c→d

Tags: logic

I don't know how to approach this question.
I thinks this is right because semantic consequence defines a syntactic consequence.
Thanks.

Thanks for the clarification.

I still don't understand if my initial question is true or not.

I wrote a prove that is true using **Eliran H** contradiction,
but if I understand **jobermark** answer so my initial question is not true.

Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea who/what you intended some prior comments for before...

Comment: @Asaf see my updated answer.

Comment: I carefully did not give a complete answer.  You asked how to *approach* it.  The other answers are correct.  In order for d to be false, one of a, b, or c must be false and false implies anything in material implication, so of course it implies d.  I just want to dissuade folks from doing your homework.  Part of the point here is that a->d is not a|=d.  The latter is realistic and the former is just convenient.

Answer (score 2):

What you have written is correct. It doesn't depend on the distinction between synatactic and semantic consequence, it is fundamentally an instance of the so-called paradoxes of material implication. The problem arises when you attempt to interpret material implication as representing "if...then" in natural language. In the propositional calculus, material implication is the nearest thing there is to a conditional, but it does not correctly capture what we ordinarily mean by conditionals, because we ordinarily use them to express a relationship between the content of the antecedent and the consequent: something like saying that the consequent follows from the antecedent. There are many alternative ways of expressing the meaning of conditionals, particularly using possible world semantics and non-classical logics. There is a huge literature on the subject: some useful books include Bennetts' Philosophical Guide to Conditionals, Rescher's Conditionals, Adams' The Logic of Conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct, and as Bumble pointed out, it shouldn't be interpreted in natural language since it shows that material implication doesn't capture implication in natural language very well.

**Solution**

Assume a,b,c ⊨ d. We want to show that a→d or b→d or c→d. The only case where this is false is where a,b,c are all true and d is false. But this contradicts a,b,c ⊨ d.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule about the double-turnstile is that when *all* of the things on the left are true in *all* interpretations, the thing on the right must be true.

Start with an interpretation.  If you are trying to prove it true, a concrete example may help indicate why it is so, and if you end up proving it false, it will be because some interpretation leaves a hole, or contradicts it.  So it pays off either way to find an interpretation either to generalize from or to transform into a counterexample.

The easiest kind of interpretation that has three factors that imply something is a description with three parts:  This is a cold can of soda.

> This is cold, This is a can, This contains soda |= This is a cold can of soda.

When all the things on the right are true, the thing on the left must be true.  So this is a potential interpretation of a, b, c |= d

> a = This is cold
>
> b = This is a can
>
> c = This contains soda
>
> d = This is a cold can of soda

So is it true that a -> d OR b -> d OR c -> d?